# Make a Horizontal Rule with Css and have margins

Tags: html, css

```
div.horizontalRule {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
    height:1px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

This is what I am doing now but the Margins seem to have no effect! I am not sure why but the text above and below this "horizontal rule" touch the horizontal rule with no margins. Is there a way to implement margins in this scenario?

http://jsfiddle.net/fwqSH/

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9, Firefox 5 and Chrome 13. What browser are you using? Edit: here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzXxc/)

Comment: A jsfiddle example would help a lot here. Why are you using an empty div? Can you get rid of it and do this instead? div.elementAbove {padding-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #d1d1d1;margin-bottom:5px}

Comment: I am using ie 9. does it work with margins? put a label above and below or something to test.

Comment: I believe the problem may be that there are divs above and below this. @Doug This is not a good solution for me since I do not kknow what type of div will be above the hr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is your not closing the div:

You cannot close a div as you did there must be a closing tag as so:

```
<div></div>
```

and not

```
<div />
```

corrected jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fwqSH/1/

**EDIT**

Final solution was to add a min-height of 1px because an empty div sometimes do weird things.

Final CSS:

```
div.horizontalRule {
    min-height: 1px;
    clear:both; width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d1d1d1;
    height:1px; padding-top:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: This is true but I still am not getting a bottom margin for some reason.

Comment: It's working by me in IE9... perhaps try adding `min-height: 1px;` maybe the problem is that the div doesn't have any content so it gets no height and so it loses some of its margins...

Comment: haha now it has a bottom margin and not a top margin. This is getting much closer though.

Comment: This worked...     min-height: 1px;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d1d1d1;
    height:1px;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;

Answer (score 2):

The reason the text below it butts right up against the line is because you didn't properly close the div. The browser sees `<div />` and thinks that the paragraph after that is **part** of the div. So change your HTML to something like this:

```
<div class="horizontalRule" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: Good catch. That makes the top margin work but not the bottom margin for me.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a horizontal rule, I recommend adding your class to the horizontal rule tag, `<hr class="horizontalRule" />`  This may help resolve some div interaction glitches.

Comment: It shouldn't be the case, but have you tried padding instead of margin?